# MappedByteBuffer and JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, memory-mapped-files

I am having a weird problem with MappedByteBuffers accessed through JNI. My goal is to use a C library to manipulate some data.

I first load a float buffer with Java code like this

```
private ByteBuffer vertices;

private void load(){
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
    FileChannel channel = inputStream.getChannel();
    vertices = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,
                NUM_VERTICES * 3 * 4); //3 floats xyz 
    inputStream.close();
    channel.close();
}
```

i then access it with JNI through GetDirectBufferAddress() like this (i am cutting down all the JNI stuff)

```
include <"my_external_header.h">

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_my_package_MyJavaClass_myMethod(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj){
    (..) //JNI get Field ids and stuff
    float(*)[3] vertices = reinterpret_cast<float(*)[3]>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(j_vertices));
    // All the data is awesome, can iterate through all the vertices, lets call our external function
    myExternalFunction(vertices);
}
```

After the GetDirectBufferAddress() call everything works great, i can iterate through all the data in the array without any problems and all the data is correct. I then pass it to an external api function residing in a different .so file.

```
extern "C" void myExternalFunction(float(*)[3] vertices){
  float x = vertices[0][0]; //This immediately causes a SIGBUS
}
```

I was able to fix this by converting the MappedByteBuffer (after the I/0 read operation) to an allocateDirect() ByteBuffer, but it forced me to an unnecessary copy, does anyone have any clue or pointers to what to read? Mmapped files seems to have some pitfalls that i can´t understand.

Comment: `SIGBUS` is often the result of an alignment issue.  First, verify that the address of `vertices` is correct.  If you've done that and it is correct, does `float x; memcpy( &x, &(vertices[0][0]), sizeof( float ) );` place the correct value in `x`?

Comment: Yes, it works, i can access the data. Can you explain me why this happens?

Comment: Your hardware platform appears to have address alignment restrictions, and the direct buffer address Java supplies does not meet those restrictions.  When you violate those restrictions the normal response is a SIGBUS signal.  See this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error  The JVM must be getting around the restrictions in a similar way.